Understanding これは参りましたね
In Kakegurui ch. 4, Yumeko lost a game and student council president taunts her. It seems like Yumeko suspects her opponent of using an underhanded trick 穴熊 to win the game and followed up with これは参りましたね.
I am unsure what she meant by that phrase. I initially thought it was a way to confess that she lost the game (this is the polite way to say 参った). After I looked up what これは参りました means, I now think she is saying something like "oh my, this is embarrassing (to you)." I checked the official English translation and it reads "well well" so I think my latter interpretation is correct?


That is a politer way to say 参った, but 参りました does not necessarily mean "I lost". Here, 参りましたね means "Oh, I'm in trouble now" or "You've got me". It's a way of acknowledging that the speaker is in a difficult situation after their opponent has made an unexpected move.
See also: 弱った vs 困った what is the difference
